# Save data to LocalStorage and then retrieve it using android Java

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am loading a local web page in my `android` app using `WebView` and my `web page` has one button (lets say "btnA"). When user clicks btnA, `javascript` function is called which saves `deviceID` in browser's `localstorage`.

Now there are couple of things that I would like to ask:

1. I am showing an alert when deviceID is saved and that alert is working fine in the app but how can I see the deviceID in my phone's browser once it is saved? I am using Chrome in my phone and I tried going to Chrome > Settings > Site Settings > Storage but nothing is there.
2. When user clicks on btnA, I want to run a background `service` after every 5 minutes which hits an `api` and I need to pass the deviceID (stored in a localStorage) as a `parameter` for the api. How would I get that deviceID from `localstorage` in my android app so I can pass it as a parameter?

This is how I am loading the webview in the app:

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/index.html");
```

This is my web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
</head>

<body>
    <button type="submit" value="Click Me" onclick="saveToLocalStorage()">Click Me</button>
    <script src="./app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my `app.js`:

```
function saveToLocalStorage() {
    var generatedString = randomString(9, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
    if(localStorage.getItem("deviceID") == null){
        localStorage.setItem("deviceID", generatedString);
        alert("DeviceID saved.")
    }

}

function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Javascriptinterface:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void deviceId(String deviceId) {
        // Do whatever you want with the deviceId
    }
}
```

And pass it to the webview:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "injectedObject");
```

Then you can send that id to the native app:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendDeviceId() {
        injectedObject.deviceId(localStorage.getItem("deviceID"));
    }
</script>
```

By calling `sendDeviceId()` from inside the website the native app should receive the stored deviceId. This could be done at the end of `saveToLocalStorage()` method.

To check the localstorage you can open the website on your smartphone in chrome browser and then connect it to a computer and visit `chrome://inspect/#devices` from the computer. This should show you opened tabs and there is a link to inspect in there and this will open the website inspector where you can check the local storage with that website in the Application tab.

Comment: this works like a charm. Can you please answer my first question? i.e. Where can I see this id being stored in localStorage in my phone's browser? Because I did navigate to my phone's chrome localStorage but nothing is there.

Comment: The webpage that I am loading is stored in android_res folder so how can I open it on Chrome?

Comment: I thought it was a website in your lan or public. If it's in the resources I suppose I would copy the website in a webserver on the computer and access to it from the chrome browser of the mobile, I know it's a mess but I can't think of a better way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213251/discussion-between-jeprubio-and-sallu-tech).