# Prevent Step Counter from Returning to 0 on App Closed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-sensors

I have a simple step counter taken from Google (https://github.com/google/simple-pedometer/blob/master/src/com/google/android/apps/simplepedometer/SimplePedometerActivity.java). I have adapted the Pedometer as below:

```
public class ActivityFragment extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener, StepListener {

    private TextView textView;
    private SimpleStepDetector simpleStepDetector;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accel;
    private static final String TEXT_NUM_STEPS = "";
    private int numSteps;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, container, false);

        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewStepCounter);
        textView.setTextSize(30);

        // Get an instance of the SensorManager
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accel = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        simpleStepDetector = new SimpleStepDetector();
        simpleStepDetector.registerListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        textView.setText(TEXT_NUM_STEPS + numSteps);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            simpleStepDetector.updateAccel(
                    event.timestamp, event.values[0], event.values[1], event.values[2]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void step(long timeNs) {
        numSteps++;
        textView.setText(TEXT_NUM_STEPS + numSteps);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, however, whenever I close the application the counter returns to 0, is there any way to prevent this happening? Had a look online, however could only find options to reset, not prevent reset.

Additional question whilst I am here, is there any way to store this to Firebase?

Comment: Have you tried to save the number of steps into Firebase database?

Comment: Not yet, I wasn't aware if the two were connected. Is Firebase the best way to stop the counter from resetting? I had planned to use it later on to store daily step count but thought there would be a way to keep it from resetting on close.

Comment: Firebase is a good solution to keep track of the steps. How you manage them it's up to you.

Comment: Okay, I will see what I can do. The challenge begins..

Answer (score 1):

You will have to look into local state persistence, Firebase is an online first suite. you can use Firestore Caching and rely on the cached version when offline, but it is highly recommended to look into local storage and updating your online presence infrequently.

Using local storage, you can handle real-time changes within your app and preserve any changes between the state when restarting or force closed by the user.

A few resources I was able to find:

- https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-store-data-locally-in-android-app-717190/
- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61638579/2301161

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Yes this sounds like what I am trying to do for the moment, would this affect anything later on when I add more users? Each user is currently registered to Firebase and I would like to house their daily activity details under their own unique IDs.

Comment: With local storage, you can add additional information, such as 'lastUpdate' timestamps, how often the user wants the updates to be, etc. it's more about state management than anything else and doing it with local storage and syncing it with Firebase will save usage when you scale with more users. just make sure the information is associated with the same user if you do support multiple users on the same device.